# AcceptTcpClient vs AcceptSocket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I want to  write a simple multi threaded server-client application
and I've stumbled on those two while creating tcplistenr

```
public void serverListenr
{
        int MessageLength=0;
        TcpListener peerListener = _infrastructure_TcpServerAndClient.CreateNewTcpListenerANDstart();
        while (true)
        {
            //var Client = peerListener.AcceptTcpClient or   peerListener.AcceptSocket(); ?? 
           new Thread(ServeData).Start(client);
        }
....
}
```

they have the same description

What is the difference between those two ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`AcceptTcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) returns [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx), whereas [`AcceptSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx). Due to this, they can also throw different errors

Naturally your next question will be what's the difference between those two. `TcpClient` is a wrapper around a `Socket`, with some minor performance implications. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685995/tcpclient-vs-socket-in-c-sharp).