# When should TcpListener.AcceptSocket be preferred over TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient?

Tags: .net, tcp, tcplistener

**TLDR;**

What are the differences in functionality and intended usage between `TcpListener.AcceptSocket(Async)` and `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(Async)`? Specifically, is `NetworkStream` of particular note?

**Full detail and background**

I'm trying to get to grips with the .NET socket functionality in order to write a server which maintains persistent TCP-IP connections for 2-way communication with multiple clients over a pre-defined protocol.

Initially Google led me to [MS' Asynchronous Socket Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example), which is heavily featured in SO questions on the topic.

Digging deeper into questions and answers, I saw people recommend using `TcpClient` / `TcpListener` over `Socket`.

Now `TcpListener` has (blocking and asynchronous versions of) two methods: `AcceptSocket`
 and `AcceptTcpClient`. MS' documentation briefly suggests the latter is simpler and the former gives more control but doesn't explain why or how. I can see from [AcceptTcpClient vs AcceptSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852969/accepttcpclient-vs-acceptsocket) and [TCPClient vs Socket in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685995/tcpclient-vs-socket-in-c-sharp) the latter gives access to a `NetworkStream` via `TcpClient` while the former exposes `Send` / `Receive` methods on `Socket` but that doesn't really explain why one is preferred.

So what are the differences and how should one choose which to use? Are there use-cases each is designed for? Why do both exist?

Comment: Basically what it comes down to is that `AcceptTcpClient` is a more specific/specialized function that returns the more specific `TcpClient` rather than the more generic `Socket` (of which `TcpClient` is an extension of).

Comment: @gmiley I feel like my question already embodies the answer to that linked one... which says very little. The question the answer links doesn't go much further. It seemed to me like `NetworkStream` was a key difference but by that point I am lost.

Comment: `Socket` is a lower-level class than `TcpClient`, offering the same functionality. If you don't need the former, you can use the latter to do the same with less code. That's all there is to it.

Comment: "if you don't need the former" - well my question asks why/when I would need the former

Comment: You would use `TcpClient` if you needed to do TCP specific operations, otherwise without that distinction it is merely a `Socket`. Similarly there is a `UdpClient` for UDP specific operations even though that is also just a `Socket` at heart.